# Google PubSub maximum number of messages per pull

Tags: c#, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm writing an ASP .NET Core application where I'm using the Google PubSub emulator where I can both publishe and subscribe to a topic. However, when I publish a "large" amount of messages 1000+, I would like to pull as many as possible.

I use the `Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1` library which provides `SubscriberServiceApiClient` to interact with their API. I pull asynchronously with the `PullAsync` method which has the parameter `maxMessages`. According to their documentation this decides the max number of messages that can be pulled by each request, however it may return fewer. If I provide an argument that specifies a `maxMessages` number above 100, it will not make a difference. This means the maximum number of messages I can receive from each request is always 100, which seems low. I've also tried to pull through their REST Api, which is also limited to 100 messages per pull.

I'm unsure whether it is due to some limit or if I'm doing something wrong. I have tried searching in their documentation and elsewhere, but without luck.

Answer (score 4):

In general, Google Cloud Pub/Sub cannot return more than 1,000 messages to a single `PullAsync` call. This may be even smaller when running through the emulator. The value of `returnImmediately` can also affect how many messages are returned. If you want to maximize the number of messages returned, then you'll want to set `returnImmediately` to `false`. However, even in this scenario, you'll not necessarily get `maxMessages` in each response; Cloud Pub/Sub tries to balance returning fuller responses with minimizing end-to-end latency by waiting too long.

In general, to maximize throughput, you'll need to have multiple `PullAsync` calls active at once. However, even better is to use [`SubscriberClient`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/api/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberClient.html), which handles the underlying requests behind the scenes for you and delivers messages to the function you specify as they arrive.

Answer (score 3):

Max messages is still capped at 1,000 messages in November 2019. Pubsub does not allow to get more messages at a time. As seen in the picture below, I tried to pull messages in a loop, with 1,000 at a time. In half of the requests it gets a lot less than the maximum amount of messages. I managed to pull around 50,000 messages within the 9 minutes maximum runtime of a Cloud Function.

An alternative solution is async subscribing to a pubsub topic with google.cloud.pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient.subscribe(). However, this solution is better suited in a long running process which you could describe as a  sort of collector sitting on a server.

[image]